# Manual classification combining bands and defining values in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, classification, image-classification, combine

I would like to perform some manual classification on a single image of S1-data which is fairly simple: either a pixel is classified as 'Water', or it is classified as 'Land'. I did these classifications separately, which results in two newly added boolean bands: it is water yes/no, and it is land yes/no. However, I would like to have my classification of 'landcover' in one single band, so I will have to combine the two bands. Also, I want my pixels classified as water to have a value 1, and my pixels classified as land to have a value of 2. I have done all the classification steps, and tried multiple solutions like joins and expressions, but they did not seem to do what I wanted. Does anyone have any tips? Here are some snips from my code:

```
var threshold = -16; 
var vv = img.select('VV_filterd'); //Note 'VV_Filtered' is processed VV-band
var water = vv.lt(threshold).rename('Water');
    water = water.updateMask(water);
    water = water.addBands(water); 
var land = vv.gte(threshold).rename('Land'); 
    land = land.updateMask(land);
    land = land.addBands(land);
```

Now I can map these layers separately, or I can simply add both bands into one image, but I want to have all my classification in one band with water having value 1 and land having value 4. Can anyone help me? Any tips on how to otherwise do this in QGIS after exporting are also welcome!

Answer (score 0):

First recall that `water` and `land` are binary images (pixel valus are 1 or 0). So to give each image a unique identifier, multiply by a constant image E.g. if you multiply each pixel in `land` by 4, land pixels would have a value of 4 and non-land pixels would retain a value of 0. As mentioned, summing over all of the images will give a single class image.

```
var water = vv.lt(threshold).rename('Water').multiply(1); // water is '1' 
var land = vv.gte(threshold).rename('Land').multiply(4);  // land is '4' 
var classimage = water.add(land)
```